# How to force resize a window to a very small size?

Tags: firefox, window-manager

I'm trying "responsive web design", modifying the code of an html page so it looks good on all devices.

I test my code with Firefox, I change the size of the window with the mouse to see how the page looks in smaller windows. However, I cannot make it really small, like the screen of a smartphone.

I tried with wnctrl but the same limits apply.

OK, I could either test the html page with a real smartphone or with an smartphone simulator. But it would really make my life easier if I could simply drag the window edge with the mouse until it got as small as the screen of a smartphone. Then, when I have a bug, I would see it happening, and I would see at what screen size it happened.

IMHO, it's related to Ubuntu and not to Firefox. All applications seem to have a minimum window width, though that width depends upon the application. I understand that the menu bar etc. of Firefox might become really snoopy if I make its window really small, but I don't care, I can always make it bigger again.

So, what is the override, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, I would use the "Responsive Design" menu.

```
Tools » Browser Tools » Responsive Design (Ctrl-Shift-M)
```

That changes the viewport to a small smartphone like size.

Resizing your window is cumbersome and it does not give you a precise size which the responsive design does. Note at the top you'll see a toolbar that you can use to switch between various settings.

Comment: Splendid, just what I needed! Thank you Alexis.